# Using SelectBoxIt in AngularJS Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to implement [SelectBoxIt](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/) in my angularJS directive. Here is my directive's template html snippet(lookup.template.html):

```
<select class="selectBoxit" ng-model="ngModel">
    <option value="" disabled> {{placeholder}}</option>
    <option value='{{a.LookupCode}}' ng-repeat='a in lookups'>{{a.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

Isolated scope directive:

```
.directive('lookup', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                lookups: "=lookups",
                ngModel: "=ngModel"
            },
            templateUrl: 'templates/lookup.template.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.placeholder = attrs['placeholder'];
                $(".selectBoxit").selectBoxIt().on('open', function()
                {
//ScrollBar
$(this).data('selectBoxSelectBoxIt').list.perfectScrollbar();
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Lookup Controller:

```
 .controller('LookupController', function($scope){
        $scope.schoolTypeCode = 'GNR';
        $scope.schoolTypes = [{  Name: "Kinder Garten",  LookupCode: "KG" },
            { Name: "Elemetary",  LookupCode: "ELM" },
            { Name: "High School",   LookupCode: "HSC" },
            { Name: "Preparatory",   LookupCode: "PRP" },
            { Name: "General",   LookupCode: "GNR" },
            {  Name: "Distance",  LookupCode: "DST"  }];
    });
```

and finally view using directive:

```
<lookup  id="cboSchoolType" lookups="schoolTypes"
                                 ng-model="SchoolTypeCode" placeholder="Select School Type"></lookup>
```

SelectBoxIt initialization worked fine but I noticed two problems. First, default value(ngModel) is not assigned and second, initialization is happenening before angular repeat finishes populating the options.This will result an empty select list and the following error message when it is clicked:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined

So, are there any other ways to set the default value and trigger SelectBoxIt initialization after options are populated by angular repeat?

Thanks.

Comment: i think you need to use setTimeout inside the link function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the "dropdown" instead of "list"

so instead of

```
$(this).data('selectBoxSelectBoxIt').list.perfectScrollbar();
```

try this line in your event function

```
$(this).data('selectBoxSelectBoxIt').dropdown.perfectScrollbar();
```